# Infinite-dimensional torsion-free $F_\infty$-group not containing $F$

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology

Is there an example of a group $G$ that has the properties

1. the cohomological dimension of $G$ is infinite: $\operatorname{cd}(G) = \infty$,
2. $G$ is torsion-free,
3. $G$ is of type $F_\infty$,
4. $G$ does not contain (an isomorphic copy of) Thompson's group $F$?

Those who don't know about Thompson's group can replace 4 by the stronger requirement

4'. $G$ does not contain an infinite-rank free abelian group.

Motivation: there are various known groups that satisfy 1-3 but all of them contain $F$. If one is bold one might wonder whether this because of what we know or because of $F$.

On a less speculative level, this is a variation of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60556/a-torsionfree-group-with-infinite-cohomological-dimension-and-no-infinitely-gene) question: two good reasons for 1 are for $G$ to have torsion or to contain infinite-rank free abelian groups. So how to assure it if the two are ruled out? The cited question did not require 3 although in comments IgorBelegradek and IanAgol speculate in that direction.

Comment: There are some recent papers on variants on Thompson's group using the group $\mathbf{Z}+\alpha\mathbf{Z}$, $\alpha$ irrational, in lieu of $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.00108, https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.02401). Might they be candidates? (Btw for a group of homeomorphisms, "contain" $F$ has its literal meaning distinct from the one you have in mind, so I'd rephrase 4. as "...not contain any isomorphic copy of Thompson's group $F$".)

Comment: @YCor: I doubt it, it is hard to keep $F$ out of a Thompson-like group, see for example Theorem 1.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04099. But more to the point, 4 is an attempt at formalizing "is not related to Thompson groups", so if there was a Thompson-like construction that avoided $F$ I would alter my question accordingly ;-). I don't see a big risk of misunderstanding "contain $F$" since my question is about abstracts groups, but I'll modify it nonetheless.

Comment: Very interesting reference! I ignored that $F$ was so unavoidable.

Comment: Are you asking a question that you know is open or do you not know whether or not that is the case?

Comment: @PauPlummer: I wouldn't ask it if it was on an open problem list if that is what you mean. But I have talked to people who might know and didn't. I am not sure how I would know for sure that a question is "open" (if it's not, like, the Riemann Hypothesis or existence of non-residually finite hyperbolic groups).

Comment: Did you try central extensions of $F$?

Comment: @Tox: No, good idea. I know that $H^2(F) = \mathbb{Z}^2$ but I will need to think about what the extensions look like. The critical question is of course about property (4).

Comment: Here is an update on central extensions: the cohomology of $F$ is nicely described by [Brown](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/394/07433). We may restrict to $F'$ which has cyclic second cohomology, since it contains copies of $F$. The central extensions of $F$ that give rise to the ones of $F'$ can be worked out of [this](https://doi.org/10.1112/jtopol/jtp033) to be $\langle A, B, Z \mid [A,Z], [B,Z], [AB^{-1},A^{-1}BA] = Z^r, [AB^{-1},A^{-2}BA^2] \rangle$ for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Tox: The answer to you suggestion is: the central extensions of $F$ contain $F$, so no candidates there. The infinite version of the above presentation has the relations $X_i^{-1} X_{i+1} X_i = X_{i+2}Z^r$ but $X_i^{-1}X_jX_i = X_{j+1}$ for $j > i+1$. As a consequence the subgroup generated by the $X_{2i}^2$ is isomorphic to $F$. And then it contains a copy of $F$ that lies in the commutator subgroup. [Both of these facts were pointed out by Matt Zaremsky.]